# Number of ways to select a subject for each day in a week.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am attempting to solve the following question:

> A student wants to make up schedule for a seven-day period during which she will study one subject each day. She is taking four subjects - Mathematics, Physics, Chemistry, and Economics. Find the number of schedules that devote at least one day to each subject.

My attempt is as follows:

On the fisrt day, I have $4$ ways, on the second day, there are $3$ ways, on the third day, there are $2$ ways, and on the fourth day, there's only $1$ way, and for the remaining $3$ days, I can select any one of the subjects

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, on 1 day I have 4 ways, on 2nd day 3 ways, 3rd day 2, 4rth day only 1 way, and rest 3 days I can select any one of the subject.. It is right

Comment: Close, but there's some cases you are missing. Please edit in your attempts into the question.

Comment: It's my first post. I will follow your suggestion. Now regarding questions still can't figure out which case are missing

Comment: Here's an example of one case you miss. What if I studied in the following order: math, math, physics, chemistry, economics, physics, chemistry? Do you count this case?

Comment: It is not necessary for her to study four different subjects on the first four days.  One way to solve this problem is to use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Another way is to consider cases.  Note that \begin{align*} 7 & = 4 + 1 + 1 + 1\\ & = 3 + 2 + 1 + 1\\ & = 2 + 2 + 2 + 1\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can you solve this problem. In that way I can easily understand it

Answer (score 1):

Labelling the subjects $A,B,C,D$, there are $3$ possible **patterns** of subjects, 4-1-1-1 of a kind, eg AAAABCD, 3-2-1-1 of a kind, eg AAABBCD, and 2-2-2-1 of a kind, eg AABBCCD
We need to determine ways to **select** subjects to fit a pattern, and **permute** over the $7$ day **period**

$4-1-1-1\;of\;a\;kind:\;[\binom 4 1\binom3 3]\times[\frac{7!}{4!}]$

$3-2-1-1\;of\;a\;kind:\;[\binom 4 1\binom 3 1\binom2 2]\times[\frac{7!}{3!2!}]$

$2-2-2-1\;of\;a\;kind:\;[\binom4 3\binom1 1]\times[\frac{7!}{2!2!2!}]$

Compute and add up